# select each 2 random records from a distinct group

Tags: postgresql, select, random

this is a screenshot of my table and my DBMS is postgresql

field_1 is the unique key of my record, field_2 is group code, field_4 is phone number.

from here I want to select 2 of any random records from a distinct group.
in other words, selecting 2 random records and group them by field_2

I only was able to make the query below.

```
 select distinct(field_2) as group_name from mytable group by 1
```

..
please help me to keep going my project :(

[image]

Comment: `distinct` is **NOT** a function.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and the expected output based on your sample data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments). It's unclear to me if the result should consist of a total of two rows or two rows **per group** (defined by `field_2`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the the query below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (field_2) *
FROM table 
ORDER BY (field_2),random() 
LIMIT 2
```

This would return 2 random records of `field_2`:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY field_2 ORDER BY (field_2 ),random()) AS r,
    t.*
  FROM
    mytable t) x
WHERE
  x.r <= 2
```

Comment: this only returns 2 records :(

Comment: but without limit 2, returns all the records with only one random selected records within a group

Comment: (SELECT DISTINCT ON (field_2) *
FROM table 
ORDER BY (field_2),random() )
Union (SELECT DISTINCT ON (field_2) *
FROM table 
ORDER BY (field_2),random() )

Answer (score 0):

you can write following query :

SELECT * FROM mytable GROUP BY field_2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,2

Comment: i guess postgresql or my version of Postgresql does not support limit #,# statement :(

Comment: @PilKwon: the answer is indeed invalid for Postgres, because Postgres uses [limit x offset y](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT)

Comment: should I switch the LIMIT 0,2 to limit 2 offset 0?

Comment: @PilKwon: you would also need to change `rand()` to `random()` as Postgres also has no `rand()` function.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know your expected output, maybe this helps you:
first order by random in the group (field_2)
select first and second field_1 and then output

```
with temp_shuffel as
(
select 
*
from public.tbl_test
order by field_2,  random()
),

temp_values as
(
select 
nth_value(field_1,1) over (PARTITION by field_2 order by field_2 rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as f1,
nth_value(field_1,2) over (PARTITION by field_2 order by field_2 rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as f2
 from temp_shuffel
)

select distinct on (f1,f2)
row1.field_1,
row1.field_2,
row1.field_4,

row2.field_1 as field2_1,
row2.field_2 as field2_2,
row2.field_4 as field2_4

from temp_values
left join public.tbl_test as row1  on row1.field_1 = temp_values.f1
left join public.tbl_test as row2 on row2.field_1 = temp_values.f2
order by f1,f2,row1.field_1
```